# How to copy value from one field to another in Word 2003

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

I'm creating a Word 2003 Template with some fields in it as these are the only bits of text that should change (things like Company Name, Address etc.).

Now, if the person using the form fills in the Company Name field at the top (which I've created as a Text Form Field), how can I reference that value elsewhere in the Template?

Comment: Please see updated answer and let me know if you have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Right click on the field then click **Properties**.
- Ensure field is named as something you can remember
- Tick the **Calculate on Exit** check box
- Click **OK** to close the dialog
- Click **Insert**->**Reference**->**Cross-reference...**
- Check that **Reference type** is set to **Bookmark** and **Insert reference** to is set to **Bookmark text**
- Select the field whose value you want to use
- Click **OK**

Note that this may not work for all field types.

If you want these references in the header they will not update automatically. To make them update automatically when user exits the source field you need to create a macro:

- Select **Tools->Macro->Macros...** from main menu
- Enter *UpdateHeader* in Macro name text box
- Click **Create**
- Using the VBA editor that pops up, replace the default code with the following:

  ```
  Sub UpdateHeader()
  Dim i As Integer

  'exit if no document is open
  If Documents.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  'Get page count
  i = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(14)

  If i >= 1 Then 'Update fields in Header
  ActiveDocument.Sections(ActiveDocument.Sections.Count) _
  .Headers(1).Range.Fields.Update
  End If

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End Sub
  ```
- Click the save icon in the VBA editor and close it
- Right-click the source field (i.e. one that contains value entered by user) and click **Properties**.
- Select *UpdateHeader* from the list of macros to run on exit
- Click OK

Comment: Thanks for the help. This nearly works except that I have to manually update the Cross-Reference field by right-clicking and Update Field. I confirmed that I have Calculate on Exit checked. Any idea why?

Comment: Are any of the fields outside of the document body (e.g. header) by any chance? If so then they will not update immediately. This is a limitation of how Word works. But if you print or save I think they should get updated.

I'm not sure of a good workaround, there are probably some macros available on the internet.